# Gdb printing long values in hex without having to guess the length

Tags: debugging, gdb

How do I print long values in gdb?
When using just `x`, i.e `x $rdi`, the value (in hex) is cut off after 8 bytes.

If I use `x/32bx`(or whatever other length), bytes are separated by spaces which is not nice, but okay. The problem is that when there's some long value I want to print, I have to guess the size and pass it to `x/`. If that value is 256 bytes long, the output will look messy, because it's separated by spaces, but it also means I have to make a lot of guesses and then look through a long and ugly string of bytes and find the place where the value ends and is followed by 0x00s (and obviously the value can have 0x00s in between which makes trying to work this out even more confusing) to be able to know how long it is.

If I try to print it as an integer, it gets cut off as well. I'd like to be able to easily tell how long a value is and not have it be cut off.

Comment: If you don't know the size, how should the debugger know?

Comment: @ssbssa Well, the debugger could do this work for me. Look where the value ends and is followed by 0x00s, and format it correctly. In fact, I don't even need to be told the size. I just want the value not to be cut off by default.

Comment: Aside from that, I'm pretty sure the debugger does know the size, because it knows how memory is structured.

Comment: What type of structure is the address $rdi is pointing to? Because from your description, it's not clear at all for me how the debugger should know where the end is.

Comment: It's pointing to a char * buffer, which is a member of a class. Therefore, members in the class will be structred something like this:  ($rbx), 0x08($rbx), 0x10($rbx), etc. I can know by looking at it how much the individual attributes take up in memory, provided I can see them all next to each other. And the debugger knows this better than me. It's interesting though what situation you have in mind where the debugger wouldn't be able to know.

Comment: That's (%rbx), not ($rbx).

Comment: Correction: This way, by looking at how individual elements are defined, I can tell how much space has been reserved for the buffer, but what I need to know is how long the buffer is at any point in time. And I don't want to have to find the class definition in the memory. However, the debugger knows all this. So it knows how much space has been reserved in memory for this char buffer and it knows at any given point in time what it's been set to and how many bytes are free. Surely this is not a difficult question to answer? When I print it, it's cut off after the 8 byte like I said.

Comment: The debugger has the class definition, you mean in the debug information?

Comment: Why does it need any debug information? I'm dealing with raw memory here.

Comment: Then how should the debugger know the layout of the structure in the memory?

Comment: Well... because it's defined somewhere and instantiated somewhere?.

Comment: Defined somewhere? Yes, that would be in the debug information.

Comment: If I knew where the class object was instatianted, I would also be able to see how much space each member took up. The debugger knows this better than me.

Comment: You mean, like your question says, by guessing? The debugger doesn't know this better than you, not without debug information.

Comment: When `new` is called, I can clearly see how much memory gets allocated for each individual member.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I guess you could see the size of the full class if you break in operator new, but not the individual members.

Comment: No, you're wrong. I don't need to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Ok, so how can you see how much memory is allocated for each individual member?

Comment: I've already explained how above :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to display long (as well as ll & ull) values is with the g modifier. For example if we have a program which just stores

```
unsigned long long int a = 1234567891234567898;
int b = 23;
unsigned long long int c = 1111111111111111111;
```

by typing x/20xg $rsp (after the values have been moved to the stack) we get

```
0x7fffffffdd90: 0x0000000000000000    0x0000001755555040
0x7fffffffdda0: 0x112210f4c023b6da    0x0f6b75ab2bc471c7
0x7fffffffddb0: 0x0000000000000000    0x00007ffff7e08b25
...
```

With the long numbers in [rsp+0x10] & [rsp+0x18] being a & c respectively, and that 0x17 in [rsp+0xc] being b.

Comment: Thanks! G indeed helps. And sorry for the late response, I've been busy.